# How can I exclude changes to the pipeline yaml file to trigger a build in azure devops?

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Working with Azure devops, and piplines yaml files. There is a trigger on the develop branch. However, when I am saving changes to the yaml file, it triggers a new build.

This happens cause the change to the yaml file is a new commit, captured by the trigger.

So my question is, how can I exclude changes to the yaml file, from triggering a new build?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> You can specify file paths to include or exclude. Note that the wildcard syntax is different between branches/tags and file paths.

```
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - docs/*
    exclude:
    - docs/README.md
```

Source: [Build Azure Repos Git or TFS Git repositories - CI triggers - Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths)

**EDIT April 2021:**

Wild cards are not supported with path filters.

Taken from that same source now:

> You can specify file paths to include or exclude.
>
> ```yaml
> # specific path build
> trigger:
>  branches:
>    include:
>    - master
>    - releases/*
>  paths:
>    include:
>    - docs
>    exclude:
>    - docs/README.md
> ```
>
> When you specify paths, you must explicitly specify branches to trigger on. You can't trigger a pipeline with only a path filter; you must also have a branch filter, and the changed files that match the path filter must be from a branch that matches the branch filter.
>
> Tips:
>
> - **Wild cards are not supported with path filters.**
> - Paths are always specified relative to the root of the repository.
> - If you don't set path filters, then the root folder of the repo is implicitly included by default.
> - If you exclude a path, you cannot also include it unless you qualify it to a deeper folder. For example if you exclude /tools then you could include /tools/trigger-runs-on-these
> - The order of path filters doesn't matter.
> - Paths in Git are case-sensitive. Be sure to use the same case as the real folders.
> - You cannot use variables in paths, as variables are evaluated at runtime (after the trigger has fired).

Comment: Wildcards aren't supported for trigger paths -- only full filenames or directory names.  I tried using *.json for trigger in an Angular build and it was just ignored.

Comment: Does this work if you also use `trigger: none`, which is used when you want to have the pipeline run based on a PR policy check in ADO only.

Comment: @greg - for pull request, you need to go to the branch policies and set the path filter there. See more info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#path-filters

Comment: Wild cards for path filters are supported since September 8, 2021. See release notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters

Answer (score 23):

With changes announced here [Support for wild cards in path filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters)
 we can now use wild cards:

> Wild cards can be used when specifying inclusion and exclusion branches for CI or PR triggers in a pipeline YAML file. However, they cannot be used when specifying path filters. For instance, you cannot include all paths that match src/app/**/myapp*. This has been pointed out as an inconvenience by several customers. This update fills this gap. Now, you can use wild card characters (**, *, or ?) when specifying path filters.

So you can now:

```yaml
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - '*'
    exclude:
    - '**/*.yml'
    - '**/*.yaml'
```

Comment: Thanks, I was specifically looking for YAML files.

Comment: Fair warning: the `**` path string is buggy and only matches nested directories.  for example excluding `**/*.md` will exclude `.md` files in nested directories (e.g. `web/README.md`, but **does not** match `.md` files in the root directory (e.g. `README.md`)