# PR Build not ignoring README.md in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a `azure-pipeline-pr.yaml` file in this format which uses the GitHub repository.

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev2
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md
    - /README.md
    
    
stages:
- stage: PR
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  displayName: prb
  jobs:
```

Directory Structure

```
app1>
  -azure-pipeline-pr.yml
  - README.md
  - src(folder)
```

The pr build is triggering correctly. I have raised a **PR** from **featurex** to **dev2** branch and a pr build is generated.

I have not closed the above PR and I make a change to the README.md file which I have excluded in the **paths:**. The PR build is again getting triggered.

Can anyone please tell me what is the mistake here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Create a new repos, will the problem recur? Have you changed settings such as build validation?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the pipeline starts from the repository construction, but sometimes it is advisable to check all directories to avoid path errors.

```
  branches:
    include:
    - dev2
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - '*'
    exclude:
    - '**/README.md'
```

Please let me know if this could help.

Comment: Thank You, tried this but still build gets triggered

Comment: This may helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/62172516/17925238